# Can't connect to database through pgbouncer from a remote place

Tags: .net, networking, firewall, npgsql, pgbouncer

I'm  developing .net application with connection to postgresql (npgsql). Due to a large amount of idle connections (npgsql can't terminate it) I had to install pgbouncer. I wrote a config file and set an auth_user_file.

pgbouncer config:

```
[databases]
dbr = host=HOST_DNS_NAME port=16252 dbname=app_database user=PGB_USER password=PGB_PASSWORD

[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 16252
listen_addr = *
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /URL_TO_AUTH_FILE/users.txt
logfile = pgbouncer.log
pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
admin_users = root
stats_users = root
default_pool_size = 50
max_client_conn = 100
log_connections = 1
log_disconnections = 1
log_pooler_errrors = 1
unix_socket_dir = /tmp
```

I allowed communication on the 16252 port (iptables)

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp  -p tcp --dport 16252 -j ACCEPT

netstat -na | grep 16252
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16252                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2726363 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.16252
```

When I connect via SSH directly to the server and I want to connect through pgbouncer locally

```
psql -h HOST_DNS_NAME -p 16252 -U PGB_USER dbr
```

everything's fine. But when I want to connect remotely from another location through pgbouncer the psql client throws me following message:

```
    psql: could not connect to server: Connection refuses <0x0000274D/10061>
    Is the server running on host HOST_DNS_NAME and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 16252
```

If I change only port to standart 5432 (direct postgresql), everything works well.

Do you have any idea?